# Include guard not working

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have as follows in my trackerFrame.h file.

It is included by trackerFrame.cpp and main.cpp and for whatever reason I am getting multiple definition problems from it when I try to compile all pertaining to the wxWidgets event table macros.

```
#ifndef TRACKER_H
#define TRACKER_H

#include <wx/wxprec.h>
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
#  include "wx/wx.h"
#endif


#include <wx/frame.h>
#include <wx/string.h>
#include <wx/menu.h>
#include <iostream>

class mainFrame : public wxFrame {
public:
    mainFrame(wxString title);
    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
private:
    void closeProgram(wxCommandEvent & event);
};


BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(mainFrame, wxFrame)
    EVT_MENU(wxID_EXIT, mainFrame::closeProgram)
END_EVENT_TABLE()

#endif
```

I am 99.9% sure that I am doing the include guards properly and I just can't figure out what is going on.

Comment: Include guards work per compilation unit, not per program.

Comment: For future reference when you mention "multiple definition problems" or any compiler/linker error you should copy-and-paste the error messages verbatim into your question.

Comment: Include guards do not protect from program-wide multiple definition problems. Include guards have never been intended to protect from program-wide multiple definition problems. It is not clear what made you conclude that your include guards are "not working". They are working perfectly fine. They just do what they are supposed to do (and don't do what they aren't supposed to do).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your include guards are correct. The problem is most likely here:

```
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(mainFrame, wxFrame)    
    EVT_MENU(wxID_EXIT, mainFrame::closeProgram)
END_EVENT_TABLE()
```

[According to the wxWidgets wiki on event tables](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Events#Event_Tables), the event table needs to be defined into a `.cpp` file. So you would have a `tracker.cpp` file that includes the `tracker.h` file and put the `BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(mainFrame, wxFrame) ...` map into the `tracker.cpp` file.

Comment: Ahhh thank you I feel so stupid now I must have just read right over that bit.